# Is there a way to turn a melee touch attack into a ranged touch attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, touch-attacks

I'm playing a Kalashtar Psion in Eberron. I'm considering taking the Quori Nightmare prestige class (from *Races of Eberron*) when I get to level 6.

Quori Nightmares gain **Disturbing Touch (Su)**, a melee touch attack that causes damage and other effects in the target.

Is there a feat, or combination of feats, or psionic power that allows me to make the touch attack as a ranged touch attack instead?

Comment: Doh! I removed those feats. Disturbing Touch is a supernatural ability.

Comment: Removed [tag:psionics] since the actual ability in question is not psionic, even if the class that grants is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's neither feat nor psionic power, the effect you want's available as a low-priced magic item and a mid-level spell.

### The Magic Item

The Web site [*Athas.org*](http://www.athas.org/) teeters on the extreme edge of *official*, saying that it

> is recognized by WotC as the Official Dark Sun site on the internet. Content created on the official website is considered to be derivative work (as it is based on the intellectual property owned by Wizards of the Coast). This means that fan-created add-ons (such as new net books, adventures, etc.) are jointly owned by both Wizards of the Coast and the creator; neither can do anything outside the official website without the permission of the other. [*sic*]

Thus in the unlikely event the DM can be convinced to allow material from *Athas.org* (Comments' experiences say most DMs won't), the [*Athasian Emporium*](http://www.athas.org/products/AE) contains the

> ***Third Eye Long Touch***
>
> The wearer of this kind of *third eye* [*MIC* 140] can use his touch attacks as if they were ranged touch attacks with a 30-foot range increment. It does not actually grant reach, and so does not help provide a flanking bonus or allow the wearer to make attacks of opportunity at any range greater than normal. The wearer uses his normal melee attack bonuses and normally affects the target with the effect of his touch if it hits, though the target of the attacks can benefit from cover or concealment.
>
> *Faint telekinesis; ML 1st; Craft Universal Item,* far hand; *Price 2,000 Cp.*

The notation *Cp*--not to be confused with *cp* meaning *copper pieces*--stands for *ceramic pieces*, the Dark Sun campaign setting's equivalent to gold pieces. (Yes, in the Dark Sun campaign setting, the most commonly encountered currency isn't *mined* but *baked*. Just go with it.)

On the right face, this is a ridiculously useful item at a very low price.

### The Spell

The 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***greater spectral hand*** [necro] (*Dragon* #303 36-7) is like the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*spectral hand*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spectralHand.htm) [necro] (*PH* 282) except that "the hand can deliver any touch range spell of 6th-level or lower. In addition, if [the caster has] a supernatural effect tied to [his] touch, such as a paralyzing touch, the *hand* can deliver that effect as well." Further, the *hand*'s 3d4 hp total is subtracted from the caster's own. (A non-*greater* yet still *spectral hand* has, instead, its 1d4 hp subtracted from its creator's hp.)

Just <sup>this</sup> far from fitting into a *wand*, one would have to cram the spell into a custom *staff of greater spectral hand* (34,050 gp; 4 lbs.) (50 charges) or talk to the DM about a different, even more custom magic item.

This is, admittedly, not a ranged touch attack and instead a means to use a *touch attack* at *range*, which may be close enough.

Comment: Huh. Well look at that. Very cool!

Comment: @GustavBertram Do note that just about *everyone* considers Athas.org material to be third-party. It’s rarely allowed outside of Dark Sun games, and it isn’t really meant to be.

Comment: @KRyan Understood. Still, it's a simple answer and may form the basis of a custom magic item available in our campaign.

Comment: @GustavBertram Oh, definitely; I've upvoted it myself. I just didn't want the quoted blurb about being "official" to give you any misconceptions on how broadly you'll find that material considered available.

Comment: @KRyan Would making the site's official-yet-rarely-acceptable status even *more* clear improve the answer?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Eh, maybe. I probably would have if I wrote it. But you are reasonably up-front.

Comment: I am so surprised that a spell exists that interacts with non-spell touch attacks in this fashion. Neat.

Comment: @KRyan I was surprised, too. I mean, it totally makes sense given the example of the [lich's paralyzing touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lich.htm)--an otherwise a *noncombat* ability given the typical lich's resources--, but I didn't expect any designer ever to *do* anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

I can state with reasonable confidence that there is no feat or item that will accomplish this. I can state with some surety that no class will do it either, though that is a more difficult statement since there are so many.

A better method would be to extend your reach. As a psionic character, you could pick up the *expansion* power to increase in size, gaining more reach. You could take the Aberration Blood and Inhuman Reach feats (*Lords of Madness*), or the Willing Deformity and Deformity (Tall) feats (*Heroes of Horror*), gaining 5 ft. reach for either combination. Or all of the above, gaining 15-20 ft. worth of reach.

Alternatively, you could talk to your DM about porting some options available for psionic powers over to this supernatural ability.

For example, there is a Reach Power metapsionic feat, which requires Enlarge Power. There is an Enlarge Supernatural Ability feat (*Tome of Magic*), so you could make that a requirement for a homebrew Reach Supernatural Ability feat, allowing a touch attack to be made at range (30 ft. is typical) once per day per time you take the feat.

Another option might be a way to allow a psicrystal to perform supernatural touch attacks, much as it can perform psionic touch attacks.

Or a way to channel a supernatural touch through a ranged weapon, making it no longer a touch attack but allowing you to try to apply the touch at range.

Comment: There is a first-level sor/wiz spell by the name of Spectral Hand that allows touch spells to be delivered at range, but I believe it can't deliver touch attacks of other types. I mention it only for the sake of completeness, not because it solves the OP's problem - but it might perhaps be used as a basis for house-ruling a more applicable equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

A possible homebrew solution would be to use spectral hand(PHB 282) through a wand or scroll and find a way to get your  GM to allow the SU ability to be considered a low level spell.

Comment: I'll do some investigation. The ideal is if there's a psionic equivalent of spectral hand.